# Using a one time login for my test suite in testNg

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, frameworks, testng, global

The code listed below is supposed to login in the 2nd `@Test` block and it will pick it up from the login file has been created. I extends the "Testbase" class. It is logging in fine, but the second code not able to pick it up from there, and again it performs the same function twice thus it opens the web browser twice.  Please any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you

```
public class Case_Trackin extends TestBase{
public WebDriver driver;


      @Test
      public void OpeningBrowser() throws IOException InterruptedException 
     {
        Login();

      }

@Test (dependsOnMethods="OpeningBrowser", alwaysRun=true )  //This block of code previews the ExcelSpreadsheet file
{       

 }



  @AfterMethod public void tearDown()
{
                   //driver.quit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have two different tests. Once the first method runs, it closes (since you are extending the `tearDown()` method). So when the second method is going to run, there will be no login thus won't be able to perform its goal.

You should include the login method call in all tests(methods in this case) that need that to perform its goals, or change your testBase from `@AfterMethod` to `@AfterClass`.

Answer (score 0):

The `@Test` will be called twice if you are passing the excel data twice. In `@AfterMethod` the quit method is commented. And make one `@Test` in one class file as possible.